# Linux 2.6.24-gentoo-r3-comtrance on x86_64 high Useage for unknown reasons

Tags: linux

I'm a complete rookie when it comes to all things Linux related so please treat me as such and assume I know nothing. That being said my Top says this:

```
top - 12:08:03 up 11 days, 15:36,  0 users,  load average: 5.47, 5.53, 5.46
Tasks: 296 total,   2 running, 294 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  6.3%us,  1.4%sy,  0.0%ni, 71.3%id, 20.6%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.3%si,  0.0%st
Mem:   8176880k total,  8118236k used,    58644k free,    89312k buffers
Swap:  1004052k total,        0k used,  1004052k free,  7235652k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
 1229 root      15  -5     0    0    0 D    1  0.0 199:28.63 kjournald          
 2946 root      20   0  1716  676  552 D    1  0.0 145:02.94 syslogd            
14553 root      20   0  2644 1268  876 R    1  0.0   0:00.34 top                
14609 postfix   20   0  7896 1884 1460 D    1  0.0   0:00.02 bounce             
14630 postfix   20   0  7896 1876 1452 R    0  0.0   0:00.00 bounce
```

And my hard drives says:

```
> df -k
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda3              4925556   4474836    200508  96% /
/dev/sda5               489992     36090    428602   8% /tmp
/dev/sda6            377951852 236171160 122581816  66% /var
none                   4088440         0   4088440   0% /dev/shm
```

It has been like it for a few days now...

I know not what is causing the high server load (Normally around 1.3) can anyone give any tips on how to track down the culprit?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check your mail queue and see how many messages are waiting to be resent. Server load can be high due to resource interrupts (busy hard disk, network driver, etc.) so if your drive is very busy with a huge number of bounces or retries to resend, that can drive the system load higher even though the console is quite responsive. System load doesn't necessarily reflect that just the CPU is busy.

Depending on what exactly you're doing with this server, you may also want to run a hacking check...chkrootkit and rkhunter, anything odd in the logs, etc. because if you're suddenly getting a very large number of bounces, you may either have something misconfigured or someone is slamming it as a mail relay (or is successfully using it as a mail relay, and you're about to be blacklisted if you're not already as a spammer).

Comment: Oh this seems very good. OK Bard, how do I check to see the mail queue as we have been having issues there over the last few days too so that really seems likely!

chkrootkit and rkhunter are installed by default yes?

Comment: they *might* be, but I doubt it for Gentoo. You may need to google the documentation for gentoo and see how to install them for you distro, then run updates to make sure you have latest signatures. Postfix, checking queues, might find a good launch point at http://www.postfix.org/QSHAPE_README.html (or any of the docs at postfix.org). Definitely want to check your logs. It sounds like you might be getting in over your head here; I'd advise finding outside help if you're unfamiliar with analyzing your server logs or your distribution's configuration details.

Comment: sudo postsuper -d ALL

and all is well... Bart, your stab in the dark was spot on.. .however we're now a spam bot host... I need to figure that out now!

and yes, I am in over my head but I'm the "IT" guy and no money to go else where :lol:

You're an angel for me.

Comment: If you're fairly certain you're hacked, you need to disconnect it from the network until you can isolate the spam-causing modifications, as every second you're sending is another second closer to blacklisting your site, or at a minimum block outgoing port 25 traffic at your router. You may need to find a way to salvage your mail store and restore your server from backup, as you can't be sure what has been modified and hidden (especially if you're rootkitted).

Comment: Monitor your network for odd traffic with another computer (you can't trust the server itself to not hide something) at your outgoing relay point if at all possible. Just because you block port 25 doesn't mean there's not something acting as a control channel on some other port from that machine, and the bad guy isn't monitoring your actions from a remote control point. Worse the server could have been monitoring traffic for passwords or sensitive information within your network by reading emails, redirecting them, or redirecting other system traffic using arp poisoning.

Comment: hmm... I can't disconnect it as I'll be killed from the big boss. We're already blacklisted I've found >.> yay... I'm going to have to try to setup some sort of monitoring. Again, thanks for the advice, I'm going to need it :(

Comment: If you don't disconnect it, you're going to continue with possible problems. What you don't know if how much data that server *may be stealing*. sensitive information in those emails? It may be uploading it. Your browsing? That machine may be monitoring it. While I doubt it, there is even the possibility that you may be downloading illegal data...porn...movies...warez...as you don't know what the remote system cracker has set up on that computer. There are cases of cracked systems being used as FTP sites or worse.

Comment: You really really need to get that system cut off. Also be aware that it's possible for your actions to be countered since as you're working on it, if it's on the network, the remote cracker can do things to the system or have it back doored to "repair" itself. I think most admins here will tell you the system needs to be wiped and rebuilt.

Comment: The boss isn't in the office, if I take it offline he'll fire me :lol:

I can't do that, but it is still sending emails so I've broken the config file in an attempt to stop them (there is no off button in this program) :(

Comment: I've found things like Searching for LOC rootkit... nothing found
Searching for Romanian rootkit...  /usr/include/file.h /usr/include/proc.h

using the chkrootkit, there are about 4 positives..